# Which ways can i go from Atlanta to Philadelphia?

Tags: usa, trains, transportation, domestic-travel

I am going to the US for the first time to attend an event in Atlanta. I have a friend whom i'd like to visit as well but she lives in Philadelphia.

Given my very limited knowledge of US travelling, i'd like to ask you guys advise on how to get there on a budget.

I've checked on flights and they aren't precisely cheap, at least on my limited budget. (I'd prefer anything below 150 USD)

Are there any trains i can ride between those cities? Any bus routes?

EDIT
It is a one way trip, I would take a plane back home from Philadelphia

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Please review our [Help Center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) regarding asking questions on this site.  As it stands the only thing we can give you is references to various search sites like Kayak, Amtrak, and Greyhound.  Furthermore constructing itineraries are specifically off topic.  Additionally you may be able to rent a car and drive over.

Comment: Is your budget for one-way or round-trip?  I don't think you will find a round-trip for anywhere near $150.  Those cities are over 1000 km apart, after all.

Comment: @NateElredge It is a one way trip

Comment: @NateEldredge Sure you would.  Try Megabus.  Round Trip about $140

Answer (score 1):

[Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Atlanta/Philadelphia) says the only sane option is to the fly, and has direct tickets from $140.

A bus would take at least 13 hours, with trains clocking in at 17+ hours, with very limited service (once a day or less).

Comment: For long distance trains in the US, one train a day isn't "limited service" but "the best you could hope for, you're lucky there's a train at all". :-)